# How to attach single onclick on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have below HTML

```
<div>
  .. have 10 divs here
</div>
```

After clicking on each `div`, I need to get the inner HTML of the div I clicked, so do I have to have add 10 on clicks each on child div, or can this be managed with one on click on parent div?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addEventListener` method ([see MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) on parent div.

```js
document.getElementById("parent-div").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
    <div>Div 4</div>
    <div>Div 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("delegate-target"))
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<div class="delegate-target">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div div");
[...div].map(val => {
    val.addEventListener("click",() => {console.log(val.innerHTML)});
});


<div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id for parent element and attach click event to parent instead of each child and then get `e.target` when clicking:

Here is working sample:

```js
document.querySelector("#parentElement").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>

</div>
```